# spark stanford parser out of memory

Tags: scala, apache-spark, stanford-nlp

I'm using StanfordCoreNLP 2.4.1 on Spark 1.5 to parse Chinese sentences, but ran into Java heap OOM exception. The code is like below:

```
val modelpath = "edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/xinhuaFactored.ser.gz"
val lp = LexicalizedParser.loadModel(modelpath)
val dataWords = data.map(x=>{
      val tokens = x.split("\t")
      val id = tokens(0)
      val word_seg = tokens(2)
      val comm_words = word_seg.split("\1").filter(_.split(":").length == 2).map(y=>(y.split(":")(0), y.split(":")(1)))
      (id, comm_words)
    }).filter(_._2.nonEmpty)
val dataSenSlice = dataWords.map(x=>{
      val id = x._1
      val comm_words = x._2
      val punctuationIndex = Array(0) ++ comm_words.zipWithIndex.filter(_._1._2 == "34").map(_._2) ++ Array(comm_words.length - 1)
      val senIndex = (punctuationIndex zip punctuationIndex.tail).filter(z => z._1 != z._2)
      val senSlice = senIndex.map(z=>{
        val begin = if (z._1 > 0) z._1 + 1 else z._1
        val end = if (z._2 == comm_words.length - 1) z._2 + 1 else z._2
        if (comm_words.slice(begin, end).filter(_._2 != "34").nonEmpty) {
          val sen = comm_words.slice(begin, end).filter(_._2 != "34").map(_._1).mkString(" ").trim
          sen
        } else ""
      }).filter(l=>l.nonEmpty && l.length<20)
      (id, senSlice)
    }).filter(_._2.nonEmpty)
val dataPoint = dataSenSlice.map(x=>{
      val id = x._1
      val senSlice = x._2
      val senParse = senSlice.map(y=>{
        StanfordNLPParser.senParse(lp, y)// java code wrapped sentence parser
      })
      id + "\t" + senParse.mkString("\1")
    })
dataPoint.saveAsTextFile(PARSED_MERGED_POI)
```

The sentence I feed into parser is a sentence concatenated by segmented words using spaces.

The exception I ran into is:

```
17/08/09 10:28:15 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1062.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1219, rz-data-hdp-dn15004.rz.******.com): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
at java.util.regex.Pattern.union(Pattern.java:5149)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Pattern.java:2513)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2030)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1964)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1665)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1337)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1022)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.matches(Pattern.java:1128)
at java.lang.String.matches(String.java:2063)
at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.ChineseUnknownWordModel.score(ChineseUnknownWordModel.java:97)
at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.BaseUnknownWordModel.score(BaseUnknownWordModel.java:124)
at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.ChineseLexicon.score(ChineseLexicon.java:54)
at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.ExhaustivePCFGParser.extractBestParse(ExhaustivePCFGParser.java:1602)
at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.ExhaustivePCFGParser.extractBestParse(ExhaustivePCFGParser.java:1634)
at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.ExhaustivePCFGParser.extractBestParse(ExhaustivePCFGParser.java:1635)
at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.ExhaustivePCFGParser.extractBestParse(ExhaustivePCFGParser.java:1635)
at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.ExhaustivePCFGParser.extractBestParse(ExhaustivePCFGParser.java:1635)
at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.ExhaustivePCFGParser.extractBestParse(ExhaustivePCFGParser.java:1635)
at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.ExhaustivePCFGParser.extractBestParse(ExhaustivePCFGParser.java:1635)
at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.ExhaustivePCFGParser.extractBestParse(ExhaustivePCFGParser.java:1635)
at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.ExhaustivePCFGParser.extractBestParse(ExhaustivePCFGParser.java:1635)
at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.ExhaustivePCFGParser.extractBestParse(ExhaustivePCFGParser.java:1635)
at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.ExhaustivePCFGParser.extractBestParse(ExhaustivePCFGParser.java:1635)
at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.ExhaustivePCFGParser.extractBestParse(ExhaustivePCFGParser.java:1635)
at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.ExhaustivePCFGParser.extractBestParse(ExhaustivePCFGParser.java:1635)
at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.ExhaustivePCFGParser.extractBestParse(ExhaustivePCFGParser.java:1635)
at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.ExhaustivePCFGParser.extractBestParse(ExhaustivePCFGParser.java:1635)
at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.ExhaustivePCFGParser.extractBestParse(ExhaustivePCFGParser.java:1635)
at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.ExhaustivePCFGParser.extractBestParse(ExhaustivePCFGParser.java:1635)
at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.ExhaustivePCFGParser.extractBestParse(ExhaustivePCFGParser.java:1635)
at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.ExhaustivePCFGParser.extractBestParse(ExhaustivePCFGParser.java:1635)
at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.ExhaustivePCFGParser.extractBestParse(ExhaustivePCFGParser.java:1635)
```

I'm wondering if I use the right way to do sentence parsing, or some other things are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions:

1. increase the number of partitions e.g.

```
    data.repartition(500)
```

Reshuffle the data in the RDD randomly to create either more or fewer partitions and balance it across them. This always shuffles all data over the network.

2. increase executor and driver memory, e.g. add 'spark-submit' parameter:

```
    --executor-memory 8G
    --driver-memory 4G
```